# jquery scroll down when div's scroll height increases

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Using this,

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.post("include/refresh.php", function (respond) {
        var oldheight = $("#chatbox").prop("scrollHeight");
        $("#chatbox").html(respond);
        var newheight = $("#chatbox").prop("scrollHeight");
    })
    if (newheight > oldheight) {
        $("#chatbox").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight;
        }, 'slow');
    } else {}
}, 200);
```

It's not working so far been trying from 4-5 hours with no luck. I printed what I'm getting from scroll height too it returns the height of div not scroll height. Used `scrolltop` from jquery it returns null. Can some one please help?

Comment: Why is this question tagged `php`? Also I see no use of `ajax` here...

Answer (score 0):

Try

Put if condition inside the `$.post` success block

and time is very less  increase time to at least `1000ms`

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.post("include/refresh.php", function (respond) {
        var oldheight = $("#chatbox").prop("scrollHeight");
        $("#chatbox").html(respond);
        var newheight = $("#chatbox").prop("scrollHeight");
        if (newheight > oldheight) {
            $("#chatbox").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight;
            }, 'slow');
        } else {}
    });
}, 200);
```

---

Better use `setTimeout`

```
function ReStart() { //create function
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $.post("include/refresh.php", function (respond) {
            var oldheight = $("#chatbox").prop("scrollHeight");
            $("#chatbox").html(respond);
            var newheight = $("#chatbox").prop("scrollHeight");
            if (newheight > oldheight) {
                $("#chatbox").animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight;
                }, 'slow');
            } else {}
            ReStart();//if post request is success than recall this function
        }).fail(function () {
            ReStart();//if post request is fail than recall this function
        });
    }, 200);
}
ReStart(); //call the function
```